# ASP.NET MVC ignoring Content-Length?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been having some problems with missing post data in ASP.NET MVC which has lead me to investigate how ASP.NET MVC deals with invalid content lengths. I had presumed that a post with a invalid content length should be ignored by MVC.NET but this doesn't seem to be the case.

As an example, try creating a new ASP.NET MVC 2 web application and add this action to the HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Test(int userID, string text)
{
    return Content("UserID = " + userID + " Text = " + text);
}
```

Try creating a simple form that posts to the above action, run fiddler and (using "Request Builder") modify the raw data so that some of the form data is missing (e.g. remove the text parameter). Before executing the request, remember to un-tick the "Fix Content-Length header" checkbox under the Request Builder options then set a break point on the code above and execute the custom http request.

I find that the request takes a lot longer than normal (30 seconds or so) but to my amazement is still processed by the controllers action. Does anyone know if this is expected behavior and, if so, what would you recommend to safeguard against invalid content-lengths?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET does not ignore the `Content-Length` request header. Consider the following controller action as an example which simply echoes back the `foo` parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string foo)
{
    return Content(foo, "text/plain");
}
```

Now let's make a valid POST request to it:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 2555))
using (var stream = client.GetStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    writer.Write(
@"POST /home/index HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:2555
Content-Length: 10
Connection: close

foo=foobar");
    writer.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

As expected this prints the response HTTP headers (which are not important) and in the body we have `foobar`. Now try reducing the `Content-Length` header of the request:

```
POST /home/index HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:2555
Content-Length: 5
Connection: close

foo=foobar
```

Which returns a single `f` in the response body. So as you can see an invalid HTTP request could lead to incorrect parsing of the parameters.

Comment: @Brian, I don't trust tools, I only trust things that I know what they are doing, like my own code :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very detailed and precise :) It still surprises me that ASP.NET is not validating the Content-Length though. In the example you used above, I'd expect setting the Content-Length to 5 (or a greater number, say 15) would represent an invalid post and I had hoped that ASP.NET would not process it? The reason I ask is that this is at the root of our current problem, we have users who's browser seems to be cutting the post data short (we're unsure why at present). We'd like to reject any posts like this, any thoughts?

Comment: @Richard, I am afraid there is not much you could do.